# onRequestPermissionsResult not called in fragment

Tags: android, android-studio, android-permissions

In a DialogFragment I call requestPermissions, I tried those codes `getActivity().requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},12);`

or

```
requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},1);
```

I use this code to get the result

```
@Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        Log.i("permission", "Request Code: "+ requestCode);
```

if I put it in my `HoneActivity` it works fine, but I need `onRequestPermissionsResult` to be called in my fragment. If I put the code in the fragment where I called `requestPermissions` it don't work anymore. I also tried with s`uper.onRequestPermissionsResult` without success. In other topics I saw that there where a bug but I checked my version and I am using `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you called this in your fragment

```
getActivity().requestPermissions(new String[{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},12);
```

then

```
 @Override
 public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
   Log.i("permission", "Request Code: "+ requestCode);
 }
```

is getting called in your activity where you are adding your fragment.

> So `requestPermissions()` in fragment and check `onRequestPermissionsResult()` in you parent activity.where you are adding you fragment.

The Reason is requestPermissions needs an activity as aurgument Check Full details [**here**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v13/app/FragmentCompat.html).

Comment: but if I call requestPermissions() directly, without getActivity(). than I was supposed the get the onRequestPermissionsResult() call in my fragment right ? and this is not working for me